# Reflected XSS in Kendo DataSourceRequest object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, xss, checkmarx

We have the below action in a controller for Kendo grid data population

```
public ActionResult GetCompanyDetails([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   var companyDetails = BusinessLayer.GetCompaniesDetail();
   return Json(companyDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

While running checkmarx scan the above method was identified for Reflected XSS vulnerability.

> Method GetCompanyDetails at line 1 of
>   wxy/xyz/Controllers/ABCController.cs gets user input for the request
>   element. This element’s value then flows through the code without
>   being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to
>   the user in method GetCompanyDetails at line 4 of
>   wxy/xyz/Controllers/ABCController.cs. This may enable a
>   Cross-Site-Scripting attack.

How to sanitize the `DataSourceRequest request` object to fix this XSS issue?

Comment: You need to sanitize the value return by : `companyDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request)` . If you do this, you will not more have any problem.

Comment: @SPoint how to sanitize the `DataSourceRequest` object returned by `companyDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request)`. it has many string properties. do we sanitize all of its string properties?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read: [OWASP CheatSheet Validation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Yes you need to validate all the data you have, format, type. Perhaps you need to parse each element of the String and convert each to one String before applying a sanitization. Another solution could be just to Encode the result of `companyDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request)`. This fight only XSS.

But the best Solution is to

1. Validate
2. Encode

This fight again Injection AND XSS

Comment: The main issue with validation of the`DataSourceRequest` object is it is not coded by us. it comes as part of `Kendo.Mvc.UI` namespace and we do not know what sort of validation or sanitization to do. for custom classes created by us, w validate all the string properties and encode them if needed. but for this class it  has lots of properties which are objects of other classes. and we dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo.Mvc.UI Grid component does its best to prevent XSS issues by encoding content during rendering. By default, the Grid encodes the content which is displayed within the cells, which means that if a user has submitted a script, the script will not execute but it will be displayed as a standard text.Have in mind that this encoding can be disabled by setting the column. Encoded configuration to false

```
columns.Bound(bank => bank.Website).Filterable(false).Encoded(false);
```

The proposed reflective XSS vulnerability is completely and totally unexploitable by modern browsers due to the following content-type:

```
return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```